# Cannot find module Angular 2 @Component

Tags: angular

I have a very simple application and I used CLI to generate it. I created my own Directory called `customers`

[image]

Inside those directories are the following:

[image]

CustomerService.ts

```
import {CustomerModel} from "../model/customer"
import {Injectable} from "@angular/core";

@Injectable
export class CustomerService {

    customer:CustomerModel[] = [
        new CustomerModel("male"),
        new CustomerModel("female"),
        new CustomerModel("male"),
        new CustomerModel("female")
    ]
}
```

CustomerController.ts

```
import {Component} from "@angular/core";
import {CustomerService} from "../service/CustomerService";
import {CustomerModel} from "../model/customer";

@Component({
    selector: 'customers',
    template: `
<div>
<form (submit)="onSubmit()">
    <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="customer.firstName">
    <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="customer.lastName">
    <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="customer.street">
    <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="customer.phoneNumber">
</form>
```

`,
    })

```
export class CustomerController {

    customer: CustomerModel = new CustomerModel();

    constructor(public customerService: CustomerService) {

    }

    onSubmit() {
        this.customerService.customer.push(this.customer);
        console.log("Push: " + this.customerService.customer);
        this.customer = new CustomerModel();
    }

}
```

CustomerSerice.ts

```
import {CustomerModel} from "../model/customer"
import {Injectable} from "@angular/core";

@Injectable
export class CustomerService {

    customer:CustomerModel[] = [
        new CustomerModel("male"),
        new CustomerModel("female"),
        new CustomerModel("male"),
        new CustomerModel("female")
    ]
}
```

I am getting the current errors: `Cannot find module 'customers/controller/CustomerController'.` and  `Argument of type '{ moduleId: string; selector: string; directive: any[]; templateUrl: string; styleUrls: string[];`

Main.ts

```
import { bootstrap } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { AppComponent, environment } from './app/';
import {CustomerController} from './app/customers/controller/CustomerController';

if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}

bootstrap(AppComponent,[CustomerController]);
```

app.component.ts

```
import {Component} from "@angular/core";
import {CustomerController} from "customers/controller/CustomerController";

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'app-root',
    directive: [CustomerController],
    templateUrl: 'app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent {
    title = 'app works!';
}
```

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Test App</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>

<app-root>Loading...</app-root>

    <script>
      System.import('system-config.js').then(function () {
        System.import('main');
      }).catch(console.error.bind(console));
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Then app.component.html

```
<h1>
  {{title}}
    <customers></customers>
</h1>
```

What I am trying to grasp is creating new directories in my application, like I did above, then reusing the `@Component` (`<customers></customers>`).

------------------------Update 1------------------------

I have done more to try and solve this and added it on Git.

https://github.com/drewjocham/Angular2TestApp

-----------------------Update 2-------------------------

I have updated my project with the answer and it compiles but my IDE is saying the following:

[image]

and

[image]

And just displaying `Loading...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting `moduleId: module.id` in yours @Component decorator in CustomerController

**UPDATE1:** 
To fix TS errors you need:

- in customer.ts remove `public` from `constructor`
- in app.component.ts replace `directive` with `directives` (add 's') and import controller properly: `import {CustomerController} from "./customers/controller/CustomerController";`
- in CustomerService.ts: 

  `import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
  @Injectable()`

Answer (score 0):

Here's what might be a better solution
Directly specify what module you want to use like this:

```
loadChildren: () => HomeModule
```

PS: Don't forget to import the module.

Answer (score 0):

I got a similar error in my unit tests using [spectator](https://github.com/ngneat/spectator) and the `createHostFactory` method, getting the following when running the test:

> Error: Cannot find component/directive function MyComponent

In my case, the problem was that the component was missing from the template that I specified.

Adding the correct HTML of the component under test solved the problem for me.