# How to find a Component's module?

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack, frontend

I'm building some logging libraries for Angular 12+. In my logging structure when my `log()` function is called from a component, I need to know which module this component belongs to.

I mean I want to know the name or Id (if have any) of the module declaring that component!

How can I find that? is there anyway?

Comment: [this can help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39373889/cannot-find-module-angular-2-component)

Comment: can you show, how are you using log in the code?

Comment: @ApoorvaChikara just think about calling a `logger.log(blah, blah)` method from a click handler for example.

Comment: log method is a static method.  You might need to check the definition using `f12` in VScode. It might tell you the module or the namespace it is in.